# How to construct multidimensional array in O(n) time using O(n) memory

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures, runtime

I am implementing a class called IntegralImage which has a 2D array as an instance variable. The 2D array represents an image with the height being the first index and the width being the second index. Is the following code construct 2D array in O(n) time with n being number of pixels(height * width) ? Also I don't understand what exactly is memory usage and how to determine it. I have to construct the array using O(n) memory.

```
private final int[][] integralImage;
private final int imageHeight; // height of image (first index)
private final int imageWidth; // width of image (second index)

public IntegralImage(int[][] image) {
    imageHeight = image.length;
    imageWidth = image[imageHeight - 1].length;
    integralImage = new int[imageHeight][imageWidth];
    int row,column;
    for(row = 0 ; row < imageHeight ; row++)
        for(column = 0 ; column < imageWidth; column++)
            integralImage[row][column] = image[row][column];

}
```

Comment: You could use [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What about my constructing algorithm ? Does it construct the array in O(n) time using O(n) memory ?

Comment: Yes. Where `n` id `row * column`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your execution time is `O(n)`, with `n` being `height * width`. Think about it. If you double the width, you double the execution time. If you double the height, you double the execution time. That is what `O(n)` means.

Your memory footprint is `width * height * size_of_int + (height + 1) * array_overhead` (one outer array plus one array per row). Except for the tiny overhead of arrays, if you double the width, you double the memory. If you double the height, you double the memory. So, `O(n)` memory.

Comment: I didn't understand the memory footprint part. What is `width * height * size_of_int + (height + 1) * array_overhead` ? Can you please explain each part of that statement ? What is array_overhead ?!

Comment: All objects have a memory overhead, meaning some extra bytes needed by the JVM to manage the object. This includes, among others, a reference to the type of object, i.e. the class that you get by calling `getClass()`. The size of that overhead depends on the JVM implementation. --- `size_of_int` is of course the 4 bytes needed to store an `int`.

Comment: We say when analyzing running time that an algorithm will not take more than `n` steps which is O(n). So what do we say when analyzing space ? The algorithm will not take more than `n` bytes ? bits ? or what ?

Comment: `O(n)` doesn't say anything about "steps". Quoting [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) on wikipedia: "In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms by **how they respond** (e.g., in their *processing time* or working *space requirements*) **to changes in input size**." --- In particular, `O(n)` means that time/space is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) to input size.